# Incomplete \iffalse: How to shift a scope in polar coordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to shift some `scope` environment according to polar variables not `xshift` and `yshift`. Assuming that this feature is not already implemented (is it?!) and I am not reinventing a wheel, I thought that would be a good opportunity to wrestle with `pgf` stuffs to do it myself.

Here is what I've tried:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}

\newcommand\object{
    \draw[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,2);
}

\newcommand\polarshift[2]{
    xshift = \pgfmathparse{multiply(#1,cos(#2))}
    yshift = \pgfmathparse{multiply(#1,sin(#2))}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \object;
    \begin{scope}[\polarshift{60}{30}]
        \object;
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But LaTeX compalains like: Incomplete \iffalse.

What is the problem with this snippet?

Comment: You define `\polarshift` with two mandatory arguments but only provide a `[`...`]`-delimited argument. Try `\begin{scope}[\polarshift{60}{30}]`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Thanks, yet that error pops up as before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an attempt to convince you to make things more Ti*k*Zy. Instead of a macro `\object` it is arguably better to define a `pic` `object`. Then the shift is just the (relative) coordinate of the `pic`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/object/.style={
    code={\draw[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,2);}}]
 \path pic{object} (30:60pt) pic{object} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the code becomes much shorter. And it is easier to customize things:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/object/.style={
    code={\draw[fill=red,pic actions] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,2);}}]
 \path pic{object} (30:60pt) pic[rotate=30,scale=1.2,dashed,draw=blue]{object} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: as for your comment: of course, your approach can be made work, too. First of all, Ti*k*Z automatically parses these expressions, so there is no need to say `\pgfmathparse`. Other than that you are missing a comma, and you need to expand the macro.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage{graphicx} %<-loaded by tikz
%\usepackage{pgf}% <- loaded by tikz

\newcommand\object{
    \draw[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,2);
}

\newcommand\polarshift[2]{
    xshift ={#1*cos(#2)},
    yshift ={#1*sin(#2)}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \object;
    \begin{scope}[style/.expanded=\polarshift{60}{30}]
        \object;
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is definitely a better approach than writing that macro. `;-)` Nevertheless, I chose the pgf way of doing to it to learn a bit about pgf. Currently, 3 (pretty experienced) users have answered this question, yet none of them fixed the problem of my code. So, I'm just wondering whether or not this thing is even doable by pgf macros! Can you please share your thoughts about this feasibility?

Comment: @Roboticist Of course your approach can be made work, too. There are two main issues, a missing comma and a missing expansion. See my addendum.

Comment: You're helpful regardless of any label you carry, marmot or cat...

Answer (score 4):

It seems that commands can't be used as option of `scope`. Try the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}

\newcommand\object{
    \draw[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,2);
}
\tikzset{polarshift/.style args={#1/#2}{xshift=#1*cos(#2),yshift=#1*sin(#2)}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \object;
    \begin{scope}[polarshift=60/30]
        \object;
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your problem correctly, just shift it to a `polar coordinate`:

`\begin{scope}[shift={(30:2)}]`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}

\newcommand\object{
    \draw[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,2);
}

%\newcommand\polarshift[2]{
%    xshift = \pgfmathparse{multiply(#1,cos(#2))}
%    yshift = \pgfmathparse{multiply(#1,sin(#2))}
%}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \object;
    \begin{scope}[shift={(30:2)}]
        \object;
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```